# Undefined Function DiffDate Error

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS TransactionDate, [Filing Date], Title, DIFFDATE(day,[Transaction Date], [Filing Date]) AS [Date Difference]
FROM AppProsHist LEFT JOIN Applications ON AppProsHist.AppID = Applications.ID
WHERE ((Description)='Non-Final Rejection')
GROUP BY AppID, Description, [Filing Date], Title, [Date Difference]
ORDER BY Min([Transaction Date]) DESC;
```

I am trying to get the difference in days from the Filling date and the transactions date and I keep receiving a Undefined Function for DiffDate... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're after DATEDIFF rather than DIFFDATE.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f

`DATEDIFF("d",[Transaction Date], [Filing Date])`